# sprite_index not working gamemaker studio 2 (GML)

Tags: gml, game-maker-studio-2

I have a small script that changes the sprite index when I press a certain key.

```
 if (key_right)
    {
    sprite_index = playerRightSpr;//<-------------
    image_speed = 1;                           //|
    }                                          //|
    if (key_left)                              //|
    {                                          //|
    sprite_index = playerLeftSpr;              //|
    image_speed = 1;                           //|
    }                                          //|
    if (key_left) && (key_right)               //|
    {                                          //|
    sprite_index = playerSpr;                  //|
    image_speed = 0;                           //|
    }                                          //|
    if (!key_right or key_left) //add this and this, doesn't work
    {                           //but it does when I remove this code.
    sprite_index = playerSpr;
    image_speed = 0;
    }
```

Is there another way to say when standing still make sprite playerSpr because the way i'm trying seems to cause conflict. 
Thanks in advance
Bhodi

Comment: Looks like your bottom if statement is missing the `!` on the last statement, that looks likely the cause. As `!` should be declared for each statement. I've also a different solution I can show in case it didn't worked out.

Comment: That didn't work, could you please tell me the other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your entity moves you can just use the speed variable to make this.
For example :

- if your entity has a positive speed (go right) you will use PlayerRightSpr
- if your entity has a negative speed (go left) you will use PlayerLeftSpr
- And if speed is 0 you use PlayerSpr

(Instead of using two different sprites you can use image_xscale too)

```
image_xscale = 1; (normal sprite)

image_xscale = -1; (flip on x axis : mirror)
```

And finally instead of this :

```
if (!key_right or key_left)
```

Use this :

`if (!key_right || !key_left)`

Or this :

```
if (key_right == 0 || key_left == 0)
```

But you are right it's not the correct way to do this

I hope this way is good

Comment: Thanks for you help. My syntax was a bit off but this worked.

Comment: No problem. It's a little difficult to understand Game maker at first times but it's really powerful

Comment: Nice job in solving the code as-is. I think I went a little overcompilated on my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my second solution. This went from my own project, so it does require changing the whole code.

I've explained each section with comments next to each lines.

Step event:

```
var hinput = 0; //hinput = Horizontal Input
hinput = keyboard_check(vk_right) - keyboard_check(vk_left); //the trick I've used to declare the movement system, based on the arrow keys. 
                                                             //pressing right = 1, pressing left = -1, pressing both or none = 0.

if (hinput != 0) //it is not 0, so the player is moving
{
    sprite_index = s_player_walk; //changes the current sprite to the walking animation
    image_xscale = hinput;        //changes the direction it's facing: 1 = right, -1 = left.
                                  //when it's 0, it keeps the last direction it faced.
} 
else //the player is not moving
{
    sprite_index = s_player_idle; //changes the current sprite to the idle animation
}
```

As for the images itself. I've used 2 seperate sprites for this: 
 `s_player_idle`, which exists of only 1 frame, and
 `s_player_walk`, which exists of 3 looping frames.

The image speed is already defined in the image editor for each seperate sprite, so it doesn't need to be defined again in the code.